# How to split a column into 3 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have already table 1 with 3 columns like this:

```
-------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------
```

and table 2:

```
----------------
|  id  |  col  |
----------------
|   1  |   2   |
|   2  |   6   |
|   3  |   1   |
|   4  |   8   |
|   5  |   9   |
|   6  |   5   |
|   7  |   4   |
|   8  |   3   |
|   9  |   7   |
----------------
```

I want to insert to table 1 from column `col` of table 2 and get the result like this:

```
-------------------
|  A  |  B  |  C  |
-------------------
|  2  |  8  |  4  |
|  6  |  9  |  3  |
|  1  |  5  |  7  |
-------------------
```

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

Comment: But u have exactly 9 records? Or is there any pattern for this?

Comment: How do you know that 1,2,3 go into column A, 4,5,6 go into column B and 7,8,9 go into column C?

Comment: please post more details about your requirements, you might get answers to your scenario in the example that does not fit your real requirment

Comment: Database tables like to grow row-wise, but your data implies growing column-wise, which can lead to an unbounded problem.  Can you clarify what you want to achieve?

Comment: @JanWalczak yes, I have exactly 9 records.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen seems like just 9 records there = )

Comment: @BeanFrog that's requirement for my exercise

Comment: How do you know what order col in table 2 appears in? SQL Server could return this column in any order it feels like, however the order appears to be important to the final result. What other columns are there in this table?

Answer (score 4):

You can try using `DENSE_RANK()` to determine each group of 3 , and then `CASE EXPRESSION` to determine `a/b/c` :

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s.col % 3 = 1 THEN s.col END) as a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.col % 3 = 2 THEN s.col END) as b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.col % 3 = 0 THEN s.col END) as c
FROM (SELECT t.col ,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY (s.col -1)/3) as group_rnk
      FROM Table2 s) s
GROUP BY s.group_rnk
```

I now see you tagged SQL-Server 2005, which doesn't have `DENSE_RANK()` yet, so you can try it with `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
INSERT INTO Table1
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk % 3 = 1 THEN s.col END) as a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk % 3 = 2 THEN s.col END) as b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN s.rnk % 3 = 0 THEN s.col END) as c
FROM (SELECT t.col ,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY t.id) as group_rnk
      FROM Table2 s) s
GROUP BY (s.group_rnk-1)/3
```

Comment: I update my question. Please refer to my new question.

Comment: How am I supposed to know the order of the numbers? Do you have another column with ID or something?

Comment: yes, suppose I have column with ID: declare @Table2 table(id int identity(1,1), col int)

Comment: @Hanaka So just replace all three `s.col % 3` with `s.Id_Col % 3` and `ORDER BY s.col` to `ORDER BY s.Id_Col`

Comment: I want to get in column A: 2, 6, 1. Follow your approach, I get in column A: 2, 8, 4

Comment: @Hanaka Please edit the question and include the `ID` column in the data sample.